# PHP script not executing upon HTML Form 'Submission'

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms, apache

I am building a website form in HTML that I want to gather information from users, and store it in MySQL. However, when I submit the form after entering the information, the PHP script is not executed. It simply displays the PHP script in raw form. In a browser, it downloads the PHP file.

At first, I was lead to believe that this was an issue with my MySQL, PHP, Apache configuration, but after following [this](http://akrabat.com/php/setting-up-php-mysql-on-os-x-10-7-lion/) step by step, I still cannot execute the PHP script.

My form's header looks like so:

```
<form id="form-settings" method="post" action="file.php">
```

file.php being the script I want to execute upon submission.

Here is my PHP script:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$link = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");

if (!$link) 
{
       die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("mysql", $link) or die("Unable to select database");

$var1=$_POST['var1'];
$var2=$_POST['var2'];
$var3=$_POST['var3'];
$var4=$_POST['var4'];
$var5=$_POST['var5'];

$query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES ('','$var1','$var2','$var3','$var4','$var5')";
mysql_query($query);

mysql_close($link); ?>
```

I can execute PHP files from the Terminal fine. I can query my MySQL table and enter info into it, but when I try to run it via the HTML form, it doesn't work. The Vars are values pulled form the HTML form. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Obviously, the php is not being recognized, but where does this issue arise from?

Comment: Little offtopic you should better not use the `mysql_` functions use better `PDO`.

Comment: Where does the php file reside and how are you accessing it in the browser?

Comment: Can you post the full HTML contents of the `form` tag?

Comment: php file is in the same directory as the html file

Comment: @PraveenKumar I don't think its an issue with the form, seems to just be the browsers reading of the php script

Comment: @DavisHunt In that case, check if your web server supports PHP. What is the web server are you using? If you are under windows, try WAMP Server.

Comment: How are you accessing the html file? Are you going in to the finder and double clicking it or running it on your localhost?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(i would post this as a comment, but i can't because I've got too little karma...)

Have a look at the logfiles, especially the error log files. They are probably in /var/log/apache2 or something. See if there is something wrong?

Is your phpinfo()-script in the same directory as the other script? Are you accessing the script with the same hostname? (127.0.0.1 vs. localhost, for example?)

Comment: my phpinfo() script is in the /Library/WebServer/Documents directory, and i run it in my browser via localhost/test.php

Comment: just to clarify: your HTML-File and the php-script triggering the error is in the same directory, and you're also accessing it via http://localhost/file.php?

Comment: hmmmm, no, different directories, let me try that

Comment: I'm using a folder on my desktop to run this thing, contains all necessary files. Do I need to put it somewhere else?

Comment: Not necessarily, but assuming that you followed the instructions, then the necessary settings (like the AllowOverride Directive) are not set in the folder on your desktop. You will need to set them for your desktop folder as well.

Comment: I got it working, put it in the WebServer directory, and launched it through a browser, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your the webserver supports PHP?

If just the souce code is served from the server that seems that PHP support is not aviable. You should contact your webhoster. Also it's possible to check other file extensions.

If you have access to the configutation install the php module for the apache.

Comment: My web server does support php becuase i can run the <? phpinfo(); ?> script in my browser.

Comment: Actually, it works with <?php phpinfo(); ?> and not <? phpinfo(); ?> But that is something I can just change in the php.ini file, correct?

Comment: Yes that is possible to disable the shorttags. This is really strange do you limit the operations to get or something like that? Do you use a .htaccess file? If yes please add it to your question.

Comment: Haven't been using a .htaccess file, I'va had trouble accessing it

Answer (score 0):

One of the Apache config files should contain the following directive:

```
AddHandler php5-script .php
```

Comment: where in the .conf file should I add this?

Comment: Globally or inside a specific Directory block. But actually, if you are able to exec phpinfo() from your browser, it means that PHP is already enabled.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, for getting these in the PHP file:

```
$var1=$_POST['var1'];
$var2=$_POST['var2'];
$var3=$_POST['var3'];
$var4=$_POST['var4'];
$var5=$_POST['var5'];
```

Your form must have stuff like:

```
<form method="post" action="file.php">
    <input type="text" name="var1" />
    <input type="text" name="var2" />
    <input type="text" name="var3" />
    <input type="text" name="var4" />
    <input type="text" name="var5" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

If this is the case with your form, I meant the `name` attributes in the input, what is the output are you getting? Are you getting unparsed PHP file???

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the case for the format of the form, the php file is downloaded when run in a browser, and simply displayed in textual form in my IDE, I would assume the browser is just not recognizing the php format. Is there some header I need in my php file?