# Trouble executing a PHP file from HTTP form submission

Tags: php, cgi

Similar question was here, but did not answer my question: [PHP script not executing upon HTML Form 'Submission'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10918990/php-script-not-executing-upon-html-form-submission)

I am hosting a webpage (`index.html`) in the root web folder on a linux box.  It is a simple page with one button input:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="cgi-bin/foo.php" method="post">
        <input type="Submit" value="TEST">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

I also have a simple PHP file (`foo.php`) that will create a simple document when run.  This file is saved in the cgi-bin folder in my root web directory.

```
<?php
   $my_file = 'foo.xml';
   $handle = fopen($my_file, 'w') or die('Cannot open file:  '.$my_file); 
   $data = '<foo>OK</foo>';
   fwrite($handle, $data);
   fclose($handle);

   echo "foo.xml file created";
?>
```

Now, the webpage serves up correctly, and I can run the PHP from the command prompt and it executes properly.  Both the .html and .php files have been given CHMOD 777 permissions.

However, trying to run .php using the web input button submission gives this error:

> 403 Forbidden The requested URL '/index.html' resolves to a file which
>   is marked executable but is not a CGI file; retrieving it is
>   forbidden.

I've been Googling how to wrap a .php file into a .cgi wrapper, but everything looks messy.  Surely there is something easy I am missing here?

Any suggestions on how to resolve this error would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks,

Comment: php shouldn't be run as a cgi, and .html files shouldn't be executable. PHP code doesn't "execute", so all you need is "read" (and possibly "write") permissions.

Comment: Marc B, are you suggesting the additional permissions could be hampering the PHP execution?  Thanks for the comment.

Comment: it would explain your error. but since it's mentioning /index.html, unless you've told your server to treat .html files as PHP scripts, not likely php-related.

Comment: Removing executable permissions from the PHP file/ HTML file are not altering the error I am receiving.  When the PHP file is not set to executable, it is served to me as a text file, with all <?php... coming through.

Answer (score 1):

Move your foo.php page into the same directory as your index.html form.

Change the target of your form to foo.php.

If your webserver is set up correctly to parse PHP it should "just work".

It's very rare these days to see php run as as a cgi script.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I tried as you suggested and it did not change the error I am receiving.  I can remove executable permissions from the .php page, and when I click the button the .php text is served to me, line for line.  When set to executable, I receive the error.

Comment: You do not have PHP set up correctly. PHP files are not set to executable. The way it works is that Apache (or whatever web server you are running) maps the extension of the filename onto whatever interpreter to use to serve the page. You should have 

AddHandler php5-script .php
AddType text/html .php

In your configuration. Then anything that ends in .php will be interpreted.

Comment: what version of Linux are you running?

Comment: I'm looking into the Apache configuration now. Linux version 3.1.0.  I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: It'll depend on your distribution (Ubuntu, Fedora, etc). Most have the configuration in /etc/httpd/conf.

Since PHP parsing is usually turned on by default for .php files, it's also possible that you have not installed the PHP module for Apache which in some distributions is distinct and separate from the command line version.